# Pull data from an API and store it in a database after processing

Tags: database, api, architecture, nosql

I don't want my application to depend on the API and for that I want to create a database, which periodically pulls data from the API, processes/refines it, and then pushes the data into the database.

The application should only communicate with the database to get whatever and whenever it requires.

On the other hand, the API and the database have their own communication channel, making both processes exclusive to each other.

Application 'A' communicates with Database 'B' only. 'B' communicates with API 'C' doing its set of tasks periodically. 'A' and 'C' don't interact.

Any suggestions for such an approach? The requirement for the database is that it must be NoSQL.

Comment: The approach is good, as you will significantly lower the calls to the API, and work with the data locally. One consideration is how good will the pulled data be (in your database) if it is not accurate after some time?

Comment: The idea is to update the database after every x hours, and also delete data that has 'expired' in the context of the application (after the x hours). Depends on how the database is structured.

Comment: Yep, then tat would solve the `old data` issue. Good.

Comment: Thank you! Ron, I'm not able to figure out 'where' to carry out these tasks (pulling data from API, pre processing, pushing to DB, removing expired content from DB) between B and C. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Well, you can use MANY Programming languages to do that, Python, PHP, C#, even command line tools, scripts like BASH.. Perl .. this is up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Wrapper with API functions prepared for your own use. Later, you can separate the functions you wrote on the Wrapper according to their fields and set up a Service structure for each field. Finally, you can use the functions you will use in the UI through the service. I also recommend using the interface for wrapper and service structures.
Thanks to the structure I mentioned, any changes in the API or changes in the service do not affect the whole program.
I hope it works for you.

Comment: Currently I'm using this approach, and it is working fine. However, my application still relies directly on the API.
The aim is to have a separate line of communication for the database and the API so I can have more control over the requests I'm making from app -> database(instead of the API, where I've to model my response variable according to what the API supports).The question of 'where' to do the pre-processing before I push the data on the database is also a point of concern.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. It's one of those that has infinite answers. But, from a high level view you already answered your own question.  A <-> B <-> C. The solution can be for example:

#### Micro services

B handles storage via a REST API

C runs a `cron` job to get from the remote API and store in B

A uses B's REST API

#### Front-end back-end

B has the `cron` method somewhere and exposes a REST API for A

#### Monolith

Run a `cron` job on A to store in database locally, then retrieve from it whenever.

Comment: Thanks. What about the preprocessing I need to do on the data after the cron job, and before storing it in B? Could you please highlight that bit as well?
Is it a part of the cron job itself?

Comment: There are million ways to do that. That question is too broad.

Comment: In response to the original answer and the last comment, I'm actually open to ideas. Do you have any specific idea that you think might be a good way to go about this, all factors combined? Happy to provide more details if you want me to. A detailed workflow process won't be necessary, a high level approach will suffice.

Comment: Set up Firebase with a schedule function to get and store the data.
Access the firebase data in the UI and do what you want

Comment: I did consider Google Cloud Platform, and Cloud Functions seems to be answer. Are you sure it allows making requests to API endpoints AND modify it before pushing to the DB? From what I've understood so far, it allows communication/storage between the application and DB only. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can literally do anything you want anywhere you want in any function. So yes.